# Is __new__ a good way to retrieve a SQLAlchemy object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-2.x

I am using SQLAlchemy and I just read about the `__new__` function. I also read the other posts here about `__new__` so I am aware of the difference to `__init__`, the order they get called and their purpose and the main message for me was: *Use `__new__` to control the creation of a new instance*.

So with that in mind, when I work with SQLAlchemy and want to retrieve an instance (and create one if it does not already exist, e.g. retrieve a User object, I normally do this:

```
user = DBSession.query(User).filter(User.id==user_id).first()
if not user:
    user = User()
```

This would either return the current user or give me a new one. Now with my new knowledge about magic, I thought something like this could be a good idea:

```
user = User(id=user_id)
```

And in my database class, I would call:

```
def __new__(cls, id=0):
    if id:
        user = DBSession.query(User).filter(User.id==id).first()
    if not id or not user:
        user = super(User, cls).__new__(cls, id=id)
    return user
```

Now this code is only a quick draft (e.g. a call to super is missing) but it should clearly point out the idea.

Now my question: **Is this a good practice or should I avoid this?** If it should be avoided: Why?

Comment: What is your "database class"?  If you do what you suggest, instantiating your class will actually return an instance of `User` instead of an instance of the class.  Why do you want to do that?  Why not just have a factory function that returns a `User` instance?

Comment: The `User` class is my database class, e.g. `class User(Base)` with `Base = declarative_base()`. Yes I could implement a factory function (i.e. a factory class or a static method/classmethod) to retrieve it, but it seems to be this is what `__new__` was build for.

Comment: This is only an opinion but I would never put a database query inside a constructor. There could be times where you just want to instantiate an object with values, like pickling or deserializing. You should have to explicitly call a query function. Bad practice.

Comment: @javex: Yes, but where are you going to put the code you posted?  You can't put that code inside the `__new__` of `User`, because it itself calls `User()`, which would lead to an infinite loop.

Comment: @BrenBarn: Okay I get the problem. I did a small alteration to my second if statement to explicitly call `__init__`, but of course I have no idea how SQLAlchemy does that (and that could also result in an infinite loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question and your comments, I would suggest you not do this, because it doesn't appear you have any reason to do so, and you don't seem to understand what you're doing.

You say that you will put certain code `__new__`.  But in the `__new__` of what?  If you have this:

```
class User(Base):
    def __new__(cls, id=0):
        if id:
            user = DBSession.query(User).filter(User.id==id).first()
        if not user:
            user = User()
        return user
```

. . . then when you try to create a `User` instance, its `__new__` will try to create another instance, and so on, leading to infinite recursion.

Using `user = User.__init__()` solves nothing.  `__init__` always returns None, so you will just be trying to create a None object.

The appropriate use case for `__new__` is when you want to change what kind of object is returned when you instantiate a class by doing `SomeClass()`.  It is rare to need to do this.  The most common case is when you want to create a user-defined class that mimics a builtin type such as `dict`, but even then you might not need to do this.

If your code works without overriding `__new__`, don't override `__new__`.  Only override it if you have a specific problem or task that can't be solved in another way.

Comment: The reason I like this answer best is because you point out that the OPs use case doesn't even require this approach. It would only be a convenience in calling the constructor. If the problem doesnt require this solution, then no reason to do it. Use a class method.

Comment: okay perfect answer. Python has a lot of magic function that one should use before doing own stuff, but this function does not belong to that group - got that now. I will find a different way.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see and unterstand, there is no reason why not to put your code into `__init__` instead of `__new__`. There are only a few and very limited - but valid - uses cases for `__new__` and you should really know what you are doing. So unless you have a very good reason, stick with `__init__`.

Comment: Because in case of `__init__`, the instance was already created and I don't want that. SQLAlchemy will create the instance itself when searching for the user, so that has to be done before `__init__` gets called. If find a lot of statements that one should avoid using `__new__` but can you explain _why_?

Comment: Use backticks to mark-up inline code. Double underscore `__` is bold.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very distinct difference between the first example (checking the return value) and the second (using the constructor immediately); and that difference is the free variable: `DBSession`.

In some cases, this difference is not interesting;  If you are only using your sqlalchemy mapped objects for database persistence; and then only in contexts where `sqlalchemy.orm.scopedsession` is permissible (exactly one session per thread). then the difference is not very interesting.

I have found it unusual for both of these conditions to hold, and often neither holds.

By doing this you are preventing the objects from being useful *outside* the context of database persistence.  By disconnecting your models from the database, your application can answer questions like "what if this object had this attribute?" in addition to questions like "does this object have this attribute?"  This gets to the crux of why we map database values as python objects, so that they can have interesting behaviors, instead of just as `dict`s, which are merely bags of attributes.

For instance, in addition to using a regular database persistent login; you might allow users to log into your site with something like OAuth.  Although you don't need to persist the users' name and password to your database, you still need to *create the `User` object* for the rest of your application to work (so that the user's gravatar shows up in the template).

The other question of implicitly accessing a particular database context *by default* is usually a bad idea.  As applications grow, the need to manage how a database gets more complicated.  Objects may be partitioned across several database hosts; you may be managing several concurrent transactions in the same thread; you might want to reuse a particular session for caching performance reasons.  The sqlalchemy `Session` class exists to address all of these peculiarities; managing them explicitly, even when you are just using the most common pattern; makes dealing with the occasional variation much easier.

A really common example of that in web apps is start-up code;  Sometimes it's neccesary to pull some key bits of data out of the database before an application is ready to serve any requests; but since there is no request to serve, where does the database connection come from?  How do you get rid of it once you've finished starting up?  These questions are usually non-issues with explicitly managed sessions.